# Books recommended to learn about atheist and/or agnostic schools of Sanatana Dharma in details

Tags: scripture, history, philosophy, book-recommendation

Which books do you recommend to learn about atheist and/or agnostic schools of Sanatana Dharma?

I haven't got any good references.

I have heard about the book known as **Sarva Darsana Sangraha** written by 14th century Hindu scholar Madhava Acharya, where he lists the major ideological schools of Sanatana Dharma. **Athiesm** was its first chapter, and a few pages were written on the same topic.

I wish to know about the philosophies of the Sanatana Dharma which believed in no god or higher power.

I have found a book called **Sankhya Karika** written on Sankhya school of philosophy. I am yet to read it. How is it? What are some more books about it?

Please suggest me a few books and/or scriptures where I can read, in details, the philosophical schools which believed in no god or higher power.

Suggestion of books which write ***about*** this philosophies are also welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda , thank you so much.